# Как лучше реализовать открытие разных версий сайта в зависимости от страны посетителя?

Tags: modx, геолокация, geoip

Есть сайт на modx, русскоязычный. Есть задача создать англоязычную версию сайта на поддомене en.mysite.com во избежании лишних гемороев к контекстами и т.д.

Необходимо, чтобы в зависимости от местонахождения посетителя изначально открывалась соответствующая версия сайта. То есть если он заходит из латвии, например, открывалась англоязычная версия, однако если он переключает на русскую - то на ней и оставался. Ну и если из России/Украины и т.д. - то открывалась рускоязычная.

Не сталкивалась ранее вообще с geoip, куда копать? Как лучше реализовать?
Или по итогу будет проще сделать английскую версию непосредственно внутри modx: mysite.com/en ?

Answer (score 2):

А точно ли надо определять страну по ip?

Дело в том, что в запросе к странице браузер посылает особый http-заголовок, указывающий, на каком языке её хочет увидеть пользователь. Например, при открытии этой страницы было послано

```
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Что означает, что:

- желательно (по умолчанию с весом 1.0) отдать страницу на российском русском (ru-RU)
- с весом 0.8 на любом русском (ru) // хм.. другие русские существуют?
- с весом 0.6 на американском английском (en-US)
- с весом 0.4 на любом английском (en)

Полагаю, было бы правильно воспользоваться этим заголовком.